# Get value of editbox of type date/time

Tags: validation, xpages, ssjs

I try to get the value of an editbox of type Date/Time. If I test it with

```
getComponent("dateField").value
```

or

```
 getComponent("dateField").getSubmittedValue();
```

and print the output to the console. It always returns "null" if the field is empty or
the field does not contain a valide date. Because of this I can't differ between invalide input and empty input.

Is there a way to get the information if the field is empty?

Comment: Speak after me: unless I have a very good reason I will not read values from the view, but only the model (MVC). So bind the field for happiness

Comment: I solved the problem by using a standard EditText and bind a jQuery datepicker to the field. Because of this I can get the input value as string and use my custom validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the refresh phase you're testing.

`getValue()` will always return blank, because only content that can be converted to the underlying data type will be passed to it. Even if you disable validation, converter checks still run, because serious errors will occur if you try to put "this is not a date" into a Date/Time.

`getSubmittedValue()` will always be null if you're checking in Invoke Application or Render Response phases. That's because during the Update Model Values phase, the `submittedValue` property is passed to the `value` property and the `submittedValue` property nulled.

If you're checking in a validator, the text value entered by the user has not yet been checked against validation rules (validation) or that it can be converted to the right data type (conversion), so `getValue()` will return the value stored last time round and `getSubmittedValue()` will give the string value (e.g. "this is not a date").

So the answer is you should be able tell whether the field is empty in a validator, but bear in mind custom validators only run if you also have a required validator.

Comment: unless you check in the validator for that field, then use "value" to get the submitted value.